# EQUIVALENCE in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have got an old fortran program from someone. According to the instructions, I should compile the program as

```
f77 aa.f bb.f cc.f -o xx.out
```

I am on Macosx arm64 and installed gfortran.

```
gfortran  aa.f bb.f cc.f -o xx.out

Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 180 at (1)
bb.f:217:48:

217 |       EQUIVALENCE( A(1), USQMAT(1) ), (UTR(1), B(1))
|                                                1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (1/2)
bb.f:217:20:

217 |       EQUIVALENCE( A(1), USQMAT(1) ), (UTR(1), B(1))
|                    1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (1/2)
bb.f:217:31:

217 |       EQUIVALENCE( A(1), USQMAT(1) ), (UTR(1), B(1))
|                               1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (1/2)
```

I am not familiar with fortran. So seeking any help. Thanks.

Searching the stack overflow and some documentation, I found out that EQUIVALENCE statement causes all of the entities in one parenthesized list to be allocated storage beginning at the same storage location. I am not sure what to check here? Is it the dimension mismatch or something else?

Here are the declarations for dimensions

```
C
      DIMENSION USQMAT(3,3),ROOT(3),A(3,3),B(3,3),UTR(6)
C
      EQUIVALENCE (AAM,USQMAT(1,1)),(BAM,USQMAT(2,2)),
     * (CAM,USQMAT(3,3))
      EQUIVALENCE (FAM,USQMAT(2,3)),(GAM,USQMAT(1,3))
     *,(HAM,USQMAT(1,2))
      EQUIVALENCE( A(1), USQMAT(1) ), (UTR(1), B(1))
```

Using f77 installed using `sudo apt install fort77` on ubuntu runing using VMware on Mac, I get some other errors;

```
f77 aa.f bb.f cc.f -o xx.out
   MAIN aa:
   resread:
   reswrite:
   sugget:
   makermat:
   transform:
   matfit:
   qkfit:
Warning on line 219: 1-dim subscript in EQUIVALENCE, 2-dim declared
Warning on line 219: 1-dim subscript in EQUIVALENCE, 2-dim declared
Warning on line 219: 1-dim subscript in EQUIVALENCE, 2-dim declared
Warning on line 403: local variable zero never used
   eigen:
Error on line 415: syntax error
Error on line 416: unclassifiable statement (starts "1cosx2,sin")
   esort:
/usr/bin/f77: aborting compilation
```

Lines 414-416 are as follows:

```
    SUBROUTINE EIGEN(A,R,N,MV)
        DOUBLE PRECISION A,R,ANORM,ANRMX,THR,X,Y,SINX,SINX2,COSX,
    1COSX2,SINCS,RANGE
```

I apologise for not being able to provide a MWE as I am not very familiar with fortran. Thanks,

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. You should show the relevant source code. See [mcve]. Namely, the declarations of all entities appearing in the error message must be shown.

Comment: Does the `f77` command (instead of `gfortran`) not work? When you install `gfortran` the `f77` command should also be available (at least on Linux, I don't know about Mac).

Comment: @k314159 Certainly not on my Linux. It may be the case on some distributions though. Often, such `f77` would just point to `gfortran`.

Comment: What are the declared array dimensions of A, USQMAT, UTR and B ?

Comment: As others have mentioned, we cannot really answer this question unless all the variable declarations are shown, or a minimal example code is given. Please [edit] the question and add the relevant details.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, note that the `equivalence` statements are almost certainly entirely unrelated to the problem: you'd see the same error message for even a `print` statement if you have the rank mismatch with those arrays. We can easily tell you what the error message means ("translating" the compiler's message to common language) but without seeing the context of the code there's not much we can say about how you can fix the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details, do not use comments

Comment: @PierU Will do that.

Comment: With regard to your ```EQUIVALENCE``` statements, you have declared rank-2 arrays like ```A(3,3)```, yet you are then trying to address them as rank-1 arrays, e.g. ```A(1)```. I don't know my Fortran history well enough to know if that has ever been legal, but it certainly isn't now. With regards to your lines 415, 416, the 1 at the start of the line 416 should have been in column 6 to signify a continuation line of 415, but at some point an extra blank (or, possibly, somebody misusing tabs) seems to have pushed it into a different column.

Comment: @lastchance Out of frustration I had replaced the line showing error with `EQUIVALENCE( A(3,3), USQMAT(3,3) ), (UTR(6), B(3,3))`. Would it be the right way?  You are right as I could not find any 1COSX2 in rest of code, hinting accidental typo. I declared variables in one line  and replaced with COSX2 instead. It complied with gfrotran with few harmless warnings. 
In case of f77 compiler, with the changes above, I get some other errors such as `undefined reference to \`sind_'` and `undefined reference to \`cosd_'`.  Which I am trying to tease. Thanks.

Comment: If the ```EQUIVALENCE``` statements are purely there to save memory then those days are long gone. If they are there as aliases then it would be better to use pointers. Sometimes they can be used to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array, but that doesn't seem to be the case here as ```UTR``` and ```B``` have different total numbers of elements. If you absolutely need them then I would ```EQUIVALENCE``` the first elements of the arrays, not the last. BTW ... fixed-form Fortran is so old that people like me have forgotten how to use it!

Comment: It's difficult to know precisely what the original developer wanted to do, but I would write instead `EQUIVALENCE( A(1,1), USQMAT(1,1) ), (UTR(1), B(1,1))`

Comment: @user1535430, you may need at some point to make your code accessible - you are fixing one error, then telling us about new ones. With regards to ```sind_``` and ```cosd_``` these probably refer to what, at the time, would have been specific compiler extensions for sine and cosine with arguments in degrees. I'm sure that you could write your own. Interestingly sind() and cosd() are set to appear in the Fortran 2023 standard - see https://wg5-fortran.org/N2201-N2250/N2212.pdf